# Nuxt add GTM (noscript) to body tag on every page / route

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement Google Tag Manager on a Nuxt app and am stuck on how to add the noscript tag to the app on every page / route inside the opening body tag. I tried creating a static script and adding the file through the nuxt config:

```js
{ src: "/scripts/gtm.js", body: true }
```

which added the file to the body but was throwing errors due to the noscript tag and nested iframe from gtm. Not sure if there is a better way to inject the actual script directly inside the body

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe
src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GT
M-4BXKY65"
height="0" width="0"
style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></n
oscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Comment: Does it really make sense to add a noscript tag to a javascript based page?

Comment: FYI Nuxt can render almost all of your page statically and later make it interactive (with JS), so it's not a bad idea at all to warn users why they might be missing out on some of the interactivity. E.g. it can prerender a form but a user won't be able to submit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Eike is correct there. Noscript is completely useless in 99.99% of GTM usage cases. It's used when a user has JS off, but unlike what you think, it won't make GTM work with no JS. In fact, only one tag can "fire" in that state and that would be a rarely used custom image tag. Most commonly used for firing pixels.

Yes, noscript implies an iframe and if your app doesn't support them, well then no noscript for you. Really, Nuxt is a front-end rendering framework. Why would you have anything in your `<noscript>` other than asking the user to enable JS in order to see the site...

Comment: I get it, thank you for input. I don't know much about GTM (first time implementing). Vendor sends me that script and says please put this on every page after body tag. Thats why I asked the question :)

Comment: Yes, vendors often send those snippets with noscript. That's considered best practice on their side. We just throw away the noscript part and the vendor never frowns upon it. Even when it's not a JS-rendered front-end of an SPA. People nowadays don't disable JS.

Answer (score 3):

The [head property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-head/) in your `nuxt.config.js` lets you define all the meta data and scripts that appear on each page. It looks like you can add a [noscript section](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#noscript) for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This applies to Nuxt v2.

I added the `noscript` GTM code through `layouts/default.vue`. Doing that inserts it into `body`, albeit not completely at the end (which is probably fine). I had to use v-html to avoid hydration mismatch errors ("*The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content.*").

```
<template>
  <noscript v-html="iFrameCode" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      iFrameCode: '<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XYXYXYX" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden" />',
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

What confused me a bit when testing the implementations was the following:

When I had JavaScript on, this is what I saw in Chrome Dev Tools:

<kbd>[image: Screenshot when JavaScript is on]</kbd>

But when I tried turning JavaScript off, the code seemed to run fine:

<kbd>[image: Screenshot when JavaScript is off]</kbd>

Comment: It interpolates the string as an actual `iframe` and since that one is an HTML tag (not some JS running), it's working. Looks totally fine for me.

Comment: @kissu Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

To add GTM's `<noscript>` after `<body>` (in this example before first `<div>`) in Nuxt 2, you can edit `nuxt.config.js`, add there a `<script>` that will add nodes you need to the DOM.

It uses the same way as Google add another `<script>` tag to the `<head>`.

(Don't forget to edit `GTM-XXXXXXX`).

```
return {
  head: {
    script: [
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        body: true,
        innerHTML: '(function(d){'
          +'var b=d.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],'
              +'n=d.createElement("noscript"),'
              +'i=d.createElement("iframe"),'
              +'c1=d.createComment("Google Tag Manager (noscript)"),'
              +'c2=d.createComment("End Google Tag Manager (noscript)");'
          +'i.src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXXX";'
          +'i.style.height="0";'
          +'i.style.width="0";'
          +'i.style.display="none";'
          +'i.style.visibility="hidden";'
          +'n.appendChild(i);'
          +'b.parentNode.insertBefore(c1,b);'
          +'b.parentNode.insertBefore(n,b);'
          +'b.parentNode.insertBefore(c2,b);'
          +'})(document);'
      },
    ]
  }
}
```